# LONG TEXT or thousands of rows, or maybe something else?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm designing a program where the user makes a single choice on thousands (or potentially millions) of people. I've thought of 2 ways of storing this in a database:
1) a separate row for each entry
2) a single long text that just appends a choice for a new person or modifies a choice for an existing person.

I'd imagine separate rows for each entry should be more efficient, but if we're talking about, let's say, hundreds of thousands of entries, then what is the network overhead I'm looking at for queries on that versus just returning a single long text and using the user's cpu to parse the text?

As an example, a single long text might be something like:

```
Data
[Person A:Choice A][Person B: Choice A][Person C: Choice C]...[Person n:Choice n]
```

Whereas multiple rows obviously would be:

```
Person    Choice
A         A
B         A
C         C
....
n         n
```

Maybe I'm not thinking of this in the right way in the first place. Is there a more efficient way of doing something like this?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Table every time. table `Person`, table `Choice`, table `PersonChoice` containing the Ids of each respective table showing the choices made. Indexable, searchable, flexible.

Comment: I guess I should also add that the user will have the ability of seeing his/her overall statistics for choices made on everyone, so I will have to access all of the user's choices anyways. Would you still recommend the tables in that case?

Comment: Definitely, Hiding data in text columns in SQL is a very bad idea. To save 1000s of rows, maybe investigate Choice Groups, to reduce the rows? Someone will be along soon and put this argument forward far more succinctly than me!

Comment: I think there must be more to it than you have said. It is not feasible for a user to make a selection on **millions** of people, unless they are grouped in some way. In which case you can look at breaking down the structure further `Person --> Group --> Choice1 | Choice2 etc`. Otherwise I would suggest table, it is much more flexible. If you are really worried about performance you could set up a nightly job to format your main table into long strings, but this would only really work if your data is not very changeable.

Comment: Thanks -- I have intentionally not supplied all of the details, but the information provided has been sufficient enough for me, tied with a few more google searches based on what you've said.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put my comments in an answer and expand in places.

Regarding your decision of `string` vs `Table`. Table every time.

A design based on table `Person (Id, Name)` , table `Choice (Id, Value)` and table `PersonChoice (Id, PersonId, ChoiceId)`. Will give you an indexable, searchable and flexible solution.

Hiding data in text columns in SQL is a very bad idea - obviously ignoring `XML` data and its datatype. But that doesn't apply here.

One solution for adding statistics at a later date could be have scheduled SQL Agent jobs running off the data parsing what and when changes were made and storing that data in separate "reporting" tables.

Something to consider in your design - to save yourself having to store and manipulate 1000s of rows - is the idea of grouping choices together. Could save you a great deal of work (both for yourself and the server).

Welcome to the world of database design!

Comment: I would just suggest that you take the Id off the PersonChoice Table, as the PK of the table would be PersonId,ChoiceId and have each of the Id's as FK to their respective tables.
Just a small suggestion like i said

Answer (score 0):

> I'd imagine separate rows for each entry should be more efficient, but
>   if we're talking about, let's say, hundreds of thousands of entries,
>   then what is the network overhead I'm looking at for queries on that
>   versus just returning a single long text and using the user's cpu to
>   parse the text?

Network overhead (as a difference between the two designs) is negligible. Essentially all you're sending to the server is your query, and all the server returns is the result set. If the result of your query is one row, the server returns only one row. If the result of your query is 10,000 rows, the server sends back 10,000 rows.

The real overhead is in execution speed *on the server* and in maintenance. The server will find indexed rows in a table quickly if you use an index. But finding the 17 in a single value like "1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 30, 27" probably won't use an index.

Values like that also lose type safety and the ability to use foreign key references and cascades.